# Did the Perseverance rover's Atlas 5 really "leap off the pad"? If so, was it because the payload is tiny, or because it's going to Mars?

Tags: launch, physics, deep-space, launch-vehicle, acceleration

Spaceflight Now's [ULA’s Atlas 5 is NASA’s go-to rocket for nuclear-powered space probes](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/07/29/ulas-atlas-5-rocket-is-nasas-go-to-launcher-for-nuclear-powered-space-probes/) quotes Tory Bruno, president and CEO of United Launch Alliance:

> **“This rocket is going to leap off the pad with this relatively tiny payload, so do not blink when they say ignition,”** said Tory Bruno, president and CEO of United Launch Alliance, the 50-50 joint venture between Boeing and Lockheed Martin that builds Atlas 5 rockets.
>
> Bruno said that the Atlas 5 rocket, set for its 85th flight since debuting in 2002, is healthy and ready for the start of Thursday morning’s countdown.
>
> “Atlas is go, Centaur is go, and we are literally chomping at the bit to take this nuclear-powered dune buggy out to Mars,” Bruno said.

I'm thinking that no matter if it is large or small, the payload is still a very small fraction of a fully fueled rocket's mass, boosters or not, and so initial lift-off acceleration wouldn't necessarily be indicative of the payload mass, but then I realized that since the payload's destination is Mars and the mission requires boosters at lift-off, it may be that the destination is more indicative of lift-off acceleration than the payload mass.

**Question:** Did the Perseverance rover's Atlas 5 really "leap off the pad"? If so, was it because the payload was tiny, or because it's going to Mars? Which has more impact on lift-off acceleration rate for a given launch vehicle?

---

[image: Tory Bruno, president and CEO of United Launch Alliance, poses with the Atlas 5 rocket that will launch NASA’s Mars 2020 Perseverance rover. Credit: NASA/Ben Smegelsky]

> Tory Bruno, president and CEO of United Launch Alliance, poses with the Atlas 5 rocket that will launch NASA’s Mars 2020 Perseverance rover. Credit: NASA/Ben Smegelsky

Comment: Tomato; tomato. The payload is tiny for a 541. But those 541s leap into the air anyways.

Comment: @AntonHengst do they leap faster with boosters than without?

Comment: Its colourful marketing language, not a technical correct description of what will happen. Its a nice, colourful, imaginative way to illustrate that its a light payload.

Comment: @Polygnome yes, but is it based in fact, or totally made-up and wrong?

Comment: The real question is, where can I get a hat like that?

Comment: @JohnHoltz while the title is based on ULA's claim, an answer should address the longer version of the question that the body of the post allows. I don't think one can gauge the mass of a payload from the take-off acceleration, but it may be possible to estimate the payload's target delta-v (indicating how far it will go) from the take-off acceleration.

Comment: [here?](https://www.tasco-safety.com/categories/hard-hats/search-hard-hats-by-design/cowboy-hard-hats.html) @OrganicMarble

Comment: @JCRM that's awesome. It's a hard hat!  I wondered why the hat band looked weird.

Comment: Ah I thought you were talking about the hard-hat (actually, this one looks like a [Vulcan](https://www.discountsafetygear.com/vucohahatres.html)) - but I guess you're actually talking about the logo.

Comment: The commentary during the launch noted that the tower was cleared in about 5 seconds, while during previous launches this was about 17 seconds. Does that qualify as "leaping"?

Comment: @Ludo ya I think that really can! Given that ratio, and with $t = \sqrt{2h/a}$, that suggests the thrust to weight ratio exceeds unity by more than ten times as much as it usually does. *Wow!*

Comment: @Lubo 17 seconds sounds unrealistically slow. Is that a typo? A quick youtube comparison with another Atlas V launch would suggest that 7 s would be right in the ballpark...

Comment: @user2705196 I also thought 17 seconds is slow, but that's what I heard during the live broadcast. Haven't had a chance yet to listen back, but you might be right that I misheard.

Comment: Even the Shuttle was only 9 or so seconds... That must be wrong...

Comment: You may have misheard, the announcer may have misspoke, the person who prepared the announcer’s cues may have mistyped. 5 vs 7 is much more plausible than 5 vs 17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the tiny payload that matters--the rocket is lighter than normal so the same thrust causes it to move faster.  This is because it's heading to Mars instead of to orbit, they are trading payload capacity for the speed needed to get there.

It's not going to make a big effect in the liftoff speed, though, the weight of the payload is quite small compared to the weight of the rest of the rocket.

Comment: I'm thinking that it's the *destination* that matters most for the initial take-off acceleration. Since a large delta-v is needed for an interplanetary transfer, they added more SRBs, and that results in a larger thrust to weight ratio excess (how much it is greater than 1:1) and therefore initial acceleration rate.

Comment: @uhoh Good point, it had more SRBs than a typical Atlas.  That's just the configuration of the rocket rather than where it's going, though.

Comment: I'm thinking that rocket's configuration is dictated by where its going; the proximal cause may be the number of boosters but the root cause is the destination.

Comment: @uhoh It's dictated by how much power is needed.  A lighter Mars probe wouldn't have needed the strap-ons, a heavy enough satellite to LEO would have.